# JavaScript REST GET in SharePoint Variable Scope Confusion

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint

With the below code I'm trying to get the number of records/rows in a SharePoint list that meet a certain criteria. I'm having trouble with variable scope however. How do I get getListData() to return numRecords so I can set it to a new variable. With the below syntax numRecords is the correct value (verified via console.log) in the onQuerySucceeded function, but undefined in the top level function.

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>

$(function () {
  var numQuals = 0;

  numQuals = getListData(1);
  alert(numQuals);
});

function getListData(myFilter) {  

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/tools/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('C&Q Documents')/items?$select=Document_x0020_TypeId&$filter=Document_x0020_TypeId eq " + myFilter,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: onQuerySucceeded,
    error: onQueryFailed
  });

}

function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
  var numRecords = 0;

  $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
    numRecords++;
  });

  console.log("in onQuerySucceeded: " + numRecords);
  return numRecords
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {console.log("query failed!");}

</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. Just needed to make the call syncronys, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/tools/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('C&Q Documents')/items?$select=Document_x0020_TypeId&$filter=Document_x0020_TypeId eq " + myFilter,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: onQuerySucceeded,
    error: onQueryFailed
});
```

Thanks to all who contributed!